# Accessing object properties in JSON with a loop

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I am trying to learn more about loops and am attempting to access object properties in JSON format.

My JS is:

```
var movies = {
  "Black Panther" : {
    "title" : "Black Panther",
    "theatricalrelease" : "2/16/2018"
  },
  "Infinity War" : {
    "title" : "Avengers: Infinity War",
    "theatricalrelease" : "5/4/2018"
  },
  "Captain Marvel" : {
    "title" : "Captain Marvel",
    "theatricalrelease" : "TBA"
  }
}

console.log(movies); //logs correctly
console.log(movies.length); //logs undefined

for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
  console.log(movies[i]); // doesn't log anything
}
```

How can I access object properties like `title` and `theatricalrelease`?

Comment: That isn't an array.

Comment: Possible duplicated question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: You should really considering using JSON.parse first it will make your life way easier, then you can just use functions like you do over an object literal

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use **`.length`** over an object, since it works over array.

However you can use **`Object.Keys.Lengh`**

```js
var movies = {
  "Black Panther" : {
    "title" : "Black Panther",
    "theatricalrelease" : "2/16/2018"
  },
  "Infinity War" : {
    "title" : "Avengers: Infinity War",
    "theatricalrelease" : "5/4/2018"
  },
  "Captain Marvel" : {
    "title" : "Captain Marvel",
    "theatricalrelease" : "TBA"
  }
}

 
console.log(Object.keys(movies).length);
for(var key in movies) {
   console.log(movies[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the title and get the length in this way :

```
var movies = {
  "Black Panther" : {
    "title" : "Black Panther",
    "theatricalrelease" : "2/16/2018"
  },
  "Infinity War" : {
    "title" : "Avengers: Infinity War",
    "theatricalrelease" : "5/4/2018"
  },
  "Captain Marvel" : {
    "title" : "Captain Marvel",
    "theatricalrelease" : "TBA"
  }
}
var totalMovies = Object.keys(movies).length;
console.log(totalMovies);

for (var key in movies) {
    if (movies.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log( movies[key].title);
        console.log( movies[key].theatricalrelease);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm late to the thread.
This will do what you want.

```js
var movies = {
  "Black Panther" : {
    "title" : "Black Panther",
    "theatricalrelease" : "2/16/2018"
  },
  "Infinity War" : {
    "title" : "Avengers: Infinity War",
    "theatricalrelease" : "5/4/2018"
  },
  "Captain Marvel" : {
    "title" : "Captain Marvel",
    "theatricalrelease" : "TBA"
  }
}

var moviesArray = Object.keys(movies);

for (var i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++) {
  var index = moviesArray[i];
  console.log( "Title: " +  movies[index].title );
  console.log( "Theatrical Release: " +  movies[index].theatricalrelease );
}
```